# Automatical update of an Appian webpage on change of task status?

Tags: refresh, local-variables, appian

We have an [Appian grid](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.3/Grid_Tutorial.html) that shows all [Appian tasks](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.3/Tasks.html) of a user. The corresponding data we obtain using [`queryProcessAnalytics()`](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.3/fnc_system_a_queryprocessanalytics.html). **How can we make this update automatically when the task status changes?**

Currently, we have stored the result of `queryProcessAnalytics()` in a [local variable](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.3/Local_Variables.html) and we set [`a!refreshVariables()`](https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.3/fnc_evaluation_a_refreshvariable.html) to refresh this variable on every "user interaction" with `refreshAlways: true`. We also added a button `Refresh` that doesn't store anything away, but simply counts as a user interaction when it is clicked. The grid then refreshes automatically when the local variable with the data changes, because the grid is set to refresh when a used/dependent local variable has changed, which mainly means that the user is forced to click on `Refresh` to ensure to be up-to-date and see latest tasks.

We consider this a workaround as the *refresh automatically on variable change* in our understanding triggers refresh of local variable (and thus the grid) only once an another local variable changes, but does not trigger a refresh `queryProcessAnalytics` would suddenly throw a different result.

Any help towards a fully automatical solution is appreciated!

We searched the Appian community but to no avail. Most entries are rather old, e.g.

- [Grid refresh not working on Load()](https://community.appian.com/discussions/f/user-interface/19102/grid-refresh-not-working-on-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `refreshInterval` within your `a!refreshVariables()`with value 0,5. It will refresh every 30 seconds.
https://docs.appian.com/suite/help/21.3/fnc_evaluation_a_refreshvariable.html

Comment: Is there a way to go below 30 seconds? The users keep complaining that they want to see their changes *immediately* (i.e. after at max 2s)...

Comment: Yes and No :) I would combine both  'refreshInterval' and refresh every after user interaction. When user  just sit and look at screen then data are refreshed every 30 seconds. If he/she use app then data are refreshed immediately. Please note that setting this up in this way may have negative impact on performance.